# Is the formula for average time spent an arbitrary concoction?

Tags: probability

> Let there be two boxes A and B. The probability that a mouse moves from A to B is 0.05. What is the average time span after which the mouse moves from A to B?

The book mentions that the answer is $\frac{1}{0.05}=20$ minutes. I have a few questions regarding this.

1. Where did we get this formula? It does sound plausible: for example, if the probability of going to $B$ is $0$, then the average time that the mouse takes to go to B= $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$. However, let the probability be $0.5$. Then the average time taken is 2 minutes. How is this intuitive? Why could it not have been 1 minute or 10 minutes? All that the probability being 0.5 tells us is that the mouse spends half the time in A and the other half in B.
2. Why minutes? Why not seconds, or hours? Isn't selecting minutes as the unit of time involved fairly arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

You are right the problem should include the time between tries. As stated all you can say is that the mouse averages $20$ tries between moves from A to B.